# Can't login after shutdown 20.04 chrome-remote-desktop issue

Tags: login, 20.04

I was forced to do hard shutdown after every thing else failed. Now  i get the login screen but after entering the password I get back to the login screen. Switching and login to tty4 is possible.
Thanks.

Comment: What is a hard shutdown? did your computer crash is you running dual boot? is your windows,bios,drivers,linux,updated? what was going on during the crash what is a hard shutdown is your system backed up?

Comment: What were you doing when "everything else failed"? You need to provide more information.

Answer (score 2):

Eventually this has nothing to do with the way the machine was shutdown.
An hour before I have installed the chrome-remote-desktop. This prevented my login.
To solve it I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to log into tty4. I ran:

```
sudo apt-get purge chrome-remote-desktop
```

and then reboot. This solved my problem.

Comment: This is actually a bug in Chrome Remote Desktop package which causes login loop. See [Log in loop after installing Chrome Remote Desktop on Kubuntu 19.04 --- 2 different systems](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/9409642).